# Ubuntu Server 16.04 name resolution does not work after joining a Windows domain

Tags: networking, server, dns

I want to use the Atlassian Confluence from an Ubuntu 16.04 Server (64 bit), just configured from Terminal in a mostly Windows rich client environment. I could set up the Server, the SSH, the PostgreSQL, the Confluence and I even could join this machine to the Windows Active Directory and Windows controlled Domain with the help of `sssd` and `realmd`.

The only thing is missing is the name resolution from Windows machines, but I want to set up that also, because I want that the Windows users do not need to use the Confluence UI by the IP address of the Ubuntu VM, instead they could use the hostname of that.

Oh, and this is a Virtual Machine on a vmWare ESXi 5.5 host as this is a company network.
The ping is working in both directions: from Ubuntu VM to Windows machines and back. I have set up static IP address, but maybe wrong (please see the config below).
The ufw daemon on the Ubuntu Server VM is running, but `ufw` reports that as inactive status.

On the Ubuntu Server I have run the `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. The VM restarted several times.

In the firm we have a QNAP NAS (Linux based). In the configuration UI of that box, I could set up (there were just few parameters) to join that box to the same Domain network. And for that hostname the name resolution is working flawlessly and instantly.

The Active Directory is a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64 bit and it is also configured to being the DNS too.

After I have read several forum posts and tutorials, I did two ways, neither resulted the working machine name resolution (I have replaced the real IP and name values):

After:

```
sudo apt install realmd sssd sssd-tools samba-common krb5-user packagekit samba-common-bin samba-libs adcli ntp
```

and setting up the npt.conf

```
sudo service ntp restart
```

1.

```
sudo kinit adminuser_from_win_domain
sudo realm join WIN.DOMAIN --verbose --user-principal=ubuntu_hostname/adminuser_from_win_domain@WIN.DOMAIN --unattended
```

2.

```
sudo kinit adminuser_from_win_domain
sudo realm join WIN.DOMAIN --verbose --user-principal=ubuntu_hostname/adminuser_from_win_domain@WIN.DOMAIN --unattended --client-software=sssd --server-software=active-directory --membership-software=adcli
sudo adcli delete-computer --verbose --domain=WIN.DOMAIN --domain-realm=WIN.DOMAIN --domain-controller=192.168.0.12 --login-user=adminuser_from_win_domain
sudo adcli join --verbose --domain=WIN.DOMAIN --domain-realm=WIN.DOMAIN --domain-controller=192.168.0.12 --fqdn=ubuntu_hostname.WIN.DOMAIN --user-principal=adminuser_from_win_domain@WIN.DOMAIN --login-type=user --login-user=adminuser_from_win_domain
sudo systemctl restart sssd.service
```

With both steps the klist and realm list are working. The Ubuntu hostname appearing in the Active Directory OU.

And here comes the config files I have set up:

*/etc/network/interfaces*

```
# The primary network interface
auto abc123
iface abc123 inet static
address 192.168.0.88
netmask 255.255.0.0
network 192.168.0.0 #I'm not sure if this correct or needed at all
broadcast 192.168.0.255 #I'm not sure if this correct or needed at all
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.12 11.22.33.41 11.22.33.42
```

*/etc/ntp.conf* (I have only added one line to the end and left on the default file content elsewhere)

```
server 192.168.0.12
```

*/etc/realmd.conf*

```
[users]
default-home = /home/%D/%U
default-shell = /bin/bash
[active-directory]
default-client = sssd
os-name = Ubuntu Linux
os-version = 16.04
[service]
automatic-install = no
[WIN.DOMAIN]
fully-qualified-names = no
automatic-id-mapping = yes
user-principal = yes
manage-system = no
computer-ou = OU=HU,DC=WIN,DC=DOMAIN
```

I'm not a sysadmin, just a programmer. So please post your answers by keeping this in your minds.
I'm not sure for example, that I should create an adminuser_from_win_domain user on the Ubuntu beforehand or not?

Please help me to being able to get the name resolution working for this Ubuntu from Windowss. I am believing in you and Ubuntu! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a Windows DNS which means the DHCP is registering DNS for the computers. As we have a static IP address on the Ubuntu server it does not have a DNS registration for it.

So only a very small step was missing: make a static DNS record for this Ubuntu server. Problem solved. The name resolution is working from Windows machines on the network. :)